# How can I use a 2D matrix as an index for 4D matrix?

Tags: matlab, matrix-indexing

How can I use a 2D matrix as an index for 4D matrix?

I have:

- A stack of seven images (15x10x3x7) in a 4D matrix called `images` in the form `[Y, X, RGB, imageIndex]`
- A corresponding index matrix `indexes` (15x10) which stores which image each pixel come from
- An output image `output = zeros(10, 15, 3, 'uint8')`

```
% for example, every pixel in image-1 is (250, 250, 250)
images = zeros(10, 15, 3, 7, 'uint8');
images(:,:,:,1) = 250;
images(:,:,:,2) = 230;
images(:,:,:,3) = 210;
images(:,:,:,4) = 190;
images(:,:,:,5) = 170;
images(:,:,:,6) = 150;
images(:,:,:,7) = 130;

% this is the index for each pixel
indexes = randi(7, 10, 15); % randomly select each pixel from the seven images
```

The code below works correctly: for each pixel, use `indexes` to choose which image it comes from

```
% create the output image
output = zeros(10, 15, 3, 'uint8');
for y = 1:10
    for x = 1:15
        output(y, x, :) = images(y, x, :, indexes(y, x));
    end
end
image(output);
```

**This is slow for larger files. Is it possible to do something like `images(indexes)`, or `someFunction(images, indexes)` to achieve the same result?**

Comment: There is a very similar question, which I have linked as duplicate. Is this homework?

Comment: Thanks for the link, I'm not sure how I missed the other post